# How to get component dependencies in Dagger 2 module using Kotlin on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have a `Dagger2 Component` for `Fragment` on Android. I initialize the component by injecting the fragments dynamically. Now, I need to provide activity context to dependencies from the fragment module. I assumed writing  a provider method with Fragment as a parameter will automatically get me the Fragment reference in the module, and I can extract the context out of it. But I can't compile my code.

The application component also offers a Context, therefore I have added a qualifier to get activity context. That shouldn't create any issues I believe. Here's my code :

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class FragmentScope

@FragmentScope
@Component(modules = [FragmentModule::class],
        dependencies = [AppComponent::class])

interface FragmentComponent {
    fun inject(myFragment: MyFragment)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun appComponent(component: AppComponent): Builder
        fun build(): FragmentComponent
    }
}

@Module
object FragmentModule {
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    @Named("Fragment")
    fun provideContext(myFragment: MyFragment): Context = myFragment.context!!
}
```

Compilation Error:

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] MyFragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
    public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                         ^
  A binding with matching key exists in component: FragmentComponent
```

Comment: If you're looking to simply get a context injected where you need, you can maintain an instance of the application context from the constructor of the module.

Comment: @ElliotM I need the activity context here. I have reasons, which are difficult to describe in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mistaking the `inject` method of the `FragmentComponent`. That will trigger an injection to the fragment, not injection of fragment to the component. If you want to get the context of the activity from the fragment, you have to pass it to your module during initialization.

```
@Module
class FragmentModule(val fragment : Fragment) {
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(): Context = fragment.context!!
}
```

Comment: I am getting a different error with this: error: @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [FragmentModule]

Comment: Why do you need the custom builder btw? Can you remove it first just to test?

Comment: I am using dependent modules. Application component is in a different Android library, so I need to make a lot of code changes to drop the custom builder.

Comment: As the error says, you are missing a setter for your fragment module. This was not required before because you defined it as a singleton. Now that you need an instance of it, you need to add a setter in the builder. Try adding this `fun fragmentModule(fragmentModule : FragmentModule) : Builder`

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Before I marke the answer accepted, I am wondering if this is the right way though. Adding the setter for fragment module now makes me pass the same instance twice: DaggerFragmentComponent
                .builder()
                .appComponent((context!!.applicationContext as MyApp).appComponent)
                .fragmentModule(FragmentModule(this))   //this#1
                .build()
                .inject(this).   //this#2

Comment: Additionally I am manually creating Module instances. Is that considered a good practice? I am new to Dagger, but I haven't see any examples do that.

Comment: Your first question is perfectly valid because of your use case. You want to be injected with activity context that can only be generated by your fragment. As per your second question, yes it is more common to create instance of modules than singletons. In this way, you can create multiple components with different module instances.

Comment: An alternative way to using fragment to generate activity context is to create an ActivityComponent and add this as a dependency to your FragmentComponent. In this way, you never have to pass the fragment to the module because the ActivityComponent will provide it for you. It's completely your preference.

Comment: Also to expand on the module instance, one of the benefits of dependency injection framework is dependency lifecycle management and scoping. Therefore, you can create objects that can act as "singletons" without really employing the singleton pattern.

Comment: Thank you @tompee! Your comments are very helpful in understanding Dagger!!